# Unable to drag li tags from source list to a empty target list using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying a drag users from one list to another list. The target list is empty. I want to drag the li tags to that empty list.
Sample html code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="sourceDiv" style="border: thick;border-color: black; border-width: thick;">
    <span>Source</span>
        <ul id="optionList">
            <li><span draggable="true">Option1</span></li>
            <li><span draggable="true">Option2</span></li>
            <li><span draggable="true">Option3</span></li>
            <li><span draggable="true">Option4</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="targetDiv"  style="border: thick;border-color: black;border-width: thick;">
    <span>Target</span>
        <ul id="optionList">

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have already tried selenium using draganddrop ,clickandHold along with moveToElement and using CTRL key and moveToElement in Actions. I also tried the drag and drop using Javascript that too did not work

Using DragandDropMethod:

```
WebElement source=By.xpath("//div[@id='sourceDiv']//ul//li");
WebElement target=By.xpath("//div[@id='targetDiv']//ul");
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilder.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
```

Using MoveToElement:

```
WebElement source=By.xpath("//div[@id='sourceDiv']//ul//li");
    WebElement target=By.xpath("//div[@id='targetDiv']//ul");
    Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
    actionBuilder.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(target).release().build().perform();
```

DragAndDrop All li tags at one go using CTRL key:

```
List<WebElement> draggables=wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(getelementbytype(accessType, accessName)));
WebElement target=By.xpath("//div[@id='targetDiv']//ul")
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform();

for (WebElement from : draggables) {
    actionBuilder.click(from).perform();

}
actionBuilder.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
            actionBuilder.moveToElement(target).release().build().perform();
```

Using JavaScript

```
    WebElement source=By.xpath("//div[@id='sourceDiv']//ul//li");
    WebElement target=By.xpath("//div[@id='targetDiv']//ul");
simulateDragAndDrop(source,target);

    public void simulateDragAndDrop(WebElement elementToDrag, WebElement target) throws Exception {

            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {" + "var event = document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");"
                    + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null);" + "   event.dataTransfer = {"
                    + "       data: {}," + "       setData: function (key, value) {"
                    + "           this.data[key] = value;" + "       }," + "       getData: function (key) {"
                    + "           return this.data[key];" + "       }" + "   };" + "   return event;" + "}" 
                    + "function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) {" + "   if (transferData !== undefined) {"
                    + "       event.dataTransfer = transferData;" + "   }" + "   if (element.dispatchEvent) {"
                    + "       element.dispatchEvent(event);" + "   } else if (element.fireEvent) {"
                    + "       element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);" + "   }" + "}" 
                    + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) {"
                    + "   var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart');" + "   dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);"
                    + "   var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');"
                    + "   dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);"
                    + "   var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');"
                    + "   dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer);" + "}"
                    + "var elementToDrag = arguments[0];" + "var target = arguments[1];"
                    + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(elementToDrag, target);", elementToDrag, target);
        }
```

In each of the methods I tried I received no error but drag and drop doesn't work.

Comment: Please change target XPath to "//div[@id='targetDiv']" and retry. it should work

Comment: I tried that it did not work :(